# ORDER BY or GROUP BY based on three columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table like this..

```
Priority | Amount | Case
P1       | 100    | 1
P1       | 200    | 2
P1       | 300    | 1
P3       | 400    | 3
```

I want to first order this by `Priority` and `Amount` (Descending) and then `Case`, to look like this.

```
Priority | Amount | Case
P1       | 300    | 1
P1       | 100    | 1
P1       | 200    | 2
P3       | 400    | 3
```

If I use `ORDER BY Priority, Amount DESC, Case` then it returns this. Where `Case` is not grouped together based on the highest `Amount` value.

```
Priority | Amount | Case
P1       | 300    | 1
P1       | 200    | 2
P1       | 100    | 1
P3       | 400    | 3
```

EDIT: Adding one more record for clarity:

```
Priority | Amount | Case
P1       | 100    | 1
P1       | 200    | 2
P1       | 300    | 1
P1       | 200    | 0   << New record
P3       | 400    | 3
```

This should return as:

```
Priority | Amount | Case
P1       | 300    | 1
P1       | 100    | 1
P1       | 200    | 0
P1       | 200    | 2
P3       | 400    | 3
```

where first it grouped by `Priority`, amongst that sorted by highest `Amount` and then within the `Amount` grouped by `Case`

Comment: Your desired output appears to need this: `ORDER BY Priority, Case, Amount DESC`  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi Tim. I have edited my question to give clearer picture. Please do look into it and suggest a solution. It's not a simple ORDER BY :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the picture is even less clear now.  Your expected output does not seem to be ordered on any of the columns, except for the `Priority` column.

Comment: @Tim - the secondary ordering (after priority) appears to be based on the *maximum* `Amount` value within each set of `Case` values.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever With the `Case` being sorted in _ascending_ order in the case of a tie for `Amount`.  Very nice catch (no wonder you are over 100K).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - really nice catch - ( (no wonder you are over 100K) :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a windowed aggregate to find the *highest* amount within each `Case`, and then use *that* for sorting:

```
declare @t table ([Priority] varchar(19) not null,Amount int not null, [Case] int not null)
insert into @t ([Priority],Amount,[Case]) values
('P1',100,1),
('P1',200,2),
('P1',300,1),
('P1',200,0),
('P3',400,3)

select
    *
from
    (
        select *,MAX(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Case]) as mAmount
        from @t
    ) t
order by [Priority],mAmount desc,[Case],Amount desc
```

Result:

```
Priority            Amount      Case        mAmount
------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
P1                  300         1           300
P1                  100         1           300
P1                  200         0           200
P1                  200         2           200
P3                  400         3           400
```

Also, please consider renaming some of your columns - I've had to wrap two in `[]` brackets because they're reserved words. It's usually better to just avoid reserved words completely.

Comment: Yep! This is does it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE SHANKATABLE (PRIORITY VARCHAR(2), AMOUNT INT, [CASE] INT)
INSERT INTO SHANKATABLE VALUES('P1',   100 , 1)
INSERT INTO SHANKATABLE VALUES ('P1',   200 , 2)
INSERT INTO SHANKATABLE VALUES ('P1',   300 , 1)
INSERT INTO SHANKATABLE VALUES ('P3',   400 , 3)
```

To achieve first result simply use below query,

Based on [**Damien_The_Unbeliever**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) answer I am just updating my answer.

```
SELECT PRIORITY,[CASE],AMOUNT
FROM   (
           SELECT PRIORITY,[CASE],AMOUNT,MAX(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY [Case]) AS mAmount
           FROM   SHANKATABLE
       ) Temp
ORDER BY
       [Priority],mAmount DESC,[Case],Amount DESC
```

[**updated sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f266/5)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Rajesh. I think I over simplified my table and question. Let's add one more row to this table 
`INSERT INTO SHANKATABLE VALUES ('P1',   200 , 0)`

Now the `Case 0` will come to the top of the table but it's `Amount` value is lesser than the highest  value in `Priority P1`. Your code will return

`PRIORITY | AMOUNT | CASEP1 | 200 | 0
P1 | 300 | 1
P1 | 100 | 1
P1 | 200 | 2
P3 | 400 | 3`

where as I'm looking for

`PRIORITY | AMOUNT | CASE
P1 | 300 | 1
P1 | 100 | 1
P1 | 200 | 0
P1 | 200 | 2
P3 | 400 | 3`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
select * from tablename ORDER BY Priority, [case] , Amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier cannot be a reserved keyword in SQL, cannot have embedded spaces, and must not include supplementary characters.

An identifier that doesn’t comply with these rules must be delimited.

For example, an attribute called 2006 is considered an irregular identifier because it starts with a digit, and therefore must be delimited as "2006" or [2006]. A regular identifier such as y2006 can be referenced without delimiters simply as y2006, or it can be optional with delimiters. You might prefer not to delimit regular identifiers because the delimiters tend to clutter the code.

Comment: Thanks Eric. However this is just a sample names I have used. My actual table does not contain the same names for columns

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
select [PRIORITY],[amount],[case] from Table
order by [PRIORITY], [CASE] asc,AMOUNT desc
```

Comment: Thanks GKarya. By default SQL uses Ascending sorting without using that. However I did try it, but it did not work.